# Title bar is missing after closing wine

Tags: wine, titlebar

I'm using wine only for chessbase 9, and after I close the program, every windows' titlebars are missing.
If i type "unity --replace" or "unity --reset" in terminal, the title bars get back, but every time I use wine, they gone. I'm using ubuntu 12.04 64bit, latest wine version, please help me.

Comment: Not much can be done, it is a known bug. See [#9933265](https://bugs.launchpad.net/compiz-core/+bug/993265) and [#1019337](https://bugs.launchpad.net/compiz-core/+bug/1019337) in LaunchPad. Wait for the fix.

Answer (score 2):

Like I said in my comment, not much can be done about this. This is a known bug in the `compiz` package:

- [Wine breaks window decorations for all applications (gtk-window-decorator crashes)](https://bugs.launchpad.net/compiz-core/+bug/993265)
- [gtk-window-decorator crashes with BadWindow (invalid Window parameter), from XGetWindowProperty() from get_frame_type()](https://bugs.launchpad.net/compiz-core/+bug/1019337)

You have to wait for a fix.

Until then, you can create a script that starts whatever program you want and restarts `gtk-window-decorator` when it exits.

Per example:

```
#!/bin/bash

wine /path/to/program.exe
gtk-window-decorator --replace &
```

Then `chmod +x your_script.sh` and use it to launch whatever the program you want to run is.